# Authenticate s3 request based on both file and request

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, jwt

Let's say I want to store some files for each user which is using my website on s3. Later I want authenticate each request to s3 to make sure that user has access to the files she is requesting. I guess this can't be done using presigned URLs or signed cookies(using cloud front). So which Amazon service should I use for that? What is the simplest way to achieve this?
Lets saying I'm authenticating users using jwt and its possible to recognize wheather a user has access to a file or not by the filename and content of the jwt.

Comment: Maybe a custom authorizer? This sounds like you need/want multitenency that (really) you should have a bucket for each user that they can access based of some sort of creds lessening the risk of user A accessing user Bs bucket

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Not sure if that's the best practice. Not an aws expert but in other domains usually creating one of something for each user is not recommended

Comment: Dropbox survived with, supposedly, 1 s3 bucket for years for all its customers. Its just incredibly risky. Abstracting it to can this customer access this bucket frees you. Not sure what other domains you mean but I would argue its bad practice to allow a single client/tenent access to all customers data as a risk.

Comment: What's wrong with presigned links? You will generate them on the fly for each user so only users that need to access a file will have access to that file, unless they share the link with someone else. If they do share the link, it will be time limited.

Comment: @DarrenForsythe Well I'm trying to prevent them from accessing each other's file. Again, not an aws expert so sorry if I was wrong. It just felt like creating a table for each user.

Comment: S3 buckets are incredibly cheap, and I may be mistaken on this, but there's no cost overhead for creating an S3 bucket just the storage. You could associate an S3 bucket with each user and ensure they only have access to their own bucket. Ruling out the ability to access others unless you misconfigure the IAM user/roles etc. There is extra overhead on cleaning e.g. what happens if a user deletes their account? etc. but there isn't a risk a user could do `/get/myinfo/<anotherUserId>/`. A weak example but the idea being a single tenant client is risky and can be move up the chain

Comment: @DarrenForsythe How would that work with a bucket per user? You can have only 100 buckets per account? If you ask aws support, maybe you can get 1000 buckets. So the service would be limited to 1000 users?

Comment: One bucket per user is not the solution, for the reason @Marcin indicates. One unique S3 prefix per user within a single bucket is typical. How do these users request files that are stored in S3? Are they always doing this within an authenticated session to your webapp backend?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that I don't have enough reputation to comment so I'll post an answer here.

One solution is:

- AWS Cognito (Federated Identities)
- S3 (one bucket)

S3 bucket policies allow you to restrict access to "user folders" equivalent here to "identity" by the prefix like `yourbucket/<cognito_identity_id>/*` Each user on your webpage will have its own federated identity.

When you create and configure the identity pool in AWS define a custom authentication provider and authenticate users "by the developer" in your backend.
Also, associate the authenticated identities to one IAM Role with access to the S3 bucket where you will keep the data. The bucket policy will take care of only allowing each user to their files and not to others. (See referenced links for policy example and more)

- [Amazon S3: Allows Amazon Cognito Users to Access Objects in Their Bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_cognito-bucket.html)
- [Access to User level folders using Amazon S3 and Cognito](https://medium.com/@inishant/access-to-user-level-folders-using-amazon-s3-and-cognito-469e80dce4c6)
- [Developer Authenticated Identities (Identity Pools)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/developer-authenticated-identities.html)